# Haskell Installation error

Tags: haskell, failed-installation

I don't have administrator rights and try to install Haskell on D drive. But at the end of the installation it is showing me an alert box with the following message:

```
Could not write updated path to HKLM
```

How to fix this issue? Please help me.

Comment: it probably wants to be run with administrative privileges.

Comment: Does the [GHC build](http://haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_2_2#windows) not work without admin privileges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the [Haskell Platform installer](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) for Windows, you should choose the "Portable" install type. In this mode the installer works as a self-extracting archive - it unpacks the files to the specified location and doesn't attempt to update any system settings. Adding an "install only for the current user" option is on my TODO list.

Answer (score 1):

The installation routine tries to edit the registry. It's a good thing this is not possible without administrator privileges.

Comment: Is there any portable haskell platform implementation?